# Reference two tables that are related to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Imagine that I have these entities: `Folder`, `Group`, `Document`.

Now, each `Folder` has many `Document`'s and these `Document`'s can have a `Group` or not, inside that `Folder`.

So, a `Folder` would contain both grouped and ungrouped `Document`'s.

How would I structure such relations?

I was thinking of two ways:

1. `Document` belongs to `Group` and `Group` belongs to `Folder`. This
   requires me to always have an "ungrouped" `Group` for every `Folder`
   (really ugly).
2. `Document` belongs to both `Folder` and `Group`, `Group` belongs to
   `Folder`. This way I have the reference to the `Folder` and the
   `Group`, where the `group_id` can be null to represent "ungrouped".
   But this opens a door for error, by assigning a `Document` to a
   `Group`/`Folder` where the `Group` doesn't belong to that `Folder`.

Neither solution seems right. This probably needs some kind of composite key and the `Document` would reference that.

What would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect your second approach to give you the least headache in a real-world application. Although it might depend on specifics of the actual application.

One other alternative is to have groups **not** belong to folders (since it wasn't an explicit requirement), so that the same `group_id` might potentially span across various folders. Then you would interpret a pair `(folder_id, group_id)` as an actual group identifier in the `Document` table.

Comment: I actually want groups to not span multiple folders, forgot to mention that.

Comment: I went with my second approach, validating the relationship in the application.